# SharePoint 2013 integration

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, integration, erp, integrate

I want to integrate SharePoint 2013 with external systems in order to generate reports using data from these systems. I would like to know some methods of integrating the SharePoint with external systems like:

Time & attendance systems.
ERP system.
EAM Enterprise Assets Management system.

Answer (score 1):

Use SP Designer and create an External Content Type.  For login to the data-source using the Secure Store Service allows you to not expose anything.  You can set up a Secure Store Service application with the credentials you need and then use that when creating the External Content Type.  If it is internal you could use the database.  Every cloud service usually exposes a web service or api.

[Create External Content Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAqx0.png)

[New External Content Type Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJEwC.png)

[Adding A Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VADLh.png)

[Specifying Connection Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z0pw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use BCS or Custom Code to connect with External Systems.